# How to pivot table for year in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query

```
SELECT mua.Id,tnk.Plate,Cast(mua.Tarih as Date) as M_Date
FROM Muayene mua 
LEFT JOIN Tanker tnk on (tnk.OID=mua.TankerId)
ORDER BY mua.Id DESC
```

[image]

But I need result to be

```
      Id    Plate         2011         2012   2013  2014   2015   2016        2017
      5     34VM7969      2011-08-02                               
      4     34VM7969                                               2016-08-19
      3     34VM7969                                                          2017-03-19
      1     34VM7969                               2014-08-08
```

How can I change my query for this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the year for each one of your date values and then PIVOT on those values. You can use a couple of different functions in SQL Server to get this.

- [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) - the syntax would be `DatePart(year, yourDate)`
- [Year](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) - syntax being `Year(yourDate)`

Either one of these will return the year for each date, you'll then place the years in your PIVOT as the new columns.

```
select plate, [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014], [2015], [2016], [2017]
from
(
  SELECT tnk.Plate, 
     Cast(mua.Tarih as Date) as M_Date,
     year(mua.Tarih) yr
  FROM Muayene mua 
  LEFT JOIN Tanker tnk 
    on (tnk.OID=mua.TankerId)
) d
pivot
(
  max(m_date)
  for yr in ([2011], [2012], [2013], [2014], [2015], [2016], [2017])
) piv;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91d75/1).  You'll notice that in this query that I removed the column `mua.Id`.  This is because when you pivot data you will group by each column in your query, since these values are distinct you'll return different rows.  By removing the column from your query, you will return a result:

```
|    PLATE |       2011 |   2012 |   2013 |       2014 |       2015 |       2016 |       2017 |
|----------|------------|--------|--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 34VM7969 | 2011-08-02 | (null) | (null) | 2014-08-08 | 2015-02-21 | 2016-08-19 | 2017-03-09 |
```

Finally, if you are going to have an unknown number of dates, then I'd suggest 2 things - use a Calendar table and then dynamic SQL.

Then Calendar table is just a list of dates that you can use for querying similar to:

```
create table calendar
(
  date datetime
);

insert into calendar
select '2011-01-01' union all
select '2012-01-01' union all
select '2013-01-01' union all
select '2014-01-01' union all
select '2015-01-01' union all
select '2016-01-01' union all
select '2016-01-01' union all
select '2017-01-01' union all
select '2018-01-01'
```

You'd then create a list of the years in a sql string and execute that string, similar to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(year(date)) 
                    from calendar
                    group by year(date)
                    order by year(date)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT plate, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select plate, 
                m_Date = convert(varchar(10), m_date, 120), 
                year(m_date) yr
              from yourquery
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(m_date)
                for yr in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99fa0a/1)

Comment: Solved by your answer.Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mehmet You are welcome, I also added a suggestion for a dynamic SQL version is you don't want to hard-code the query.

Comment: Second solution is great for me.