# Group data from the last N years

Tags: sql-server

I have the tables

```
create table classroom(classID int, name nvarchar(50), year int)
create table subject(subjectId int, subjectName nvarchar(50) )
create table Approved(answerId int, total int, classID int,subjectId int)
```

I want to get a query so I can list the results of the exams from the last N years (from now):

```
TITLE : # of students approved in : 15. History
classroom Name | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017|
------------------------------------------------
1st grade     |   10  | 20   |  5   |  20  | 30
2st grade     |   3   | 50   |  5   |  60  | 40
3st grade     |   10  | 20   |  7   |  20  | 30
```

Is it possible to get this results using a procedure that expects as parameter the last N years from the current one?

Comment: Where is your sql query?

Comment: have no idea where to start. Even some guidelines about converting cell values (years) into columns will be appreciated .

Comment: And also, why would you want to do this is a procedure?  By providing a variable number of columns almost every piece of software designed to use stored procedures as a data source will break as soon as you ask for a different number of years.

Comment: @Flezcano you can start with dynamic sql + pivot. Or dynamic sql + case aggregates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: This is best dealt with in your presentation layer.  Where are you wanting to display this data?

Comment: Within a simple html table

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev thanks I will start there.

Comment: @Flezcano cloudsafe gave you the right link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot table for year in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201292/how-to-pivot-table-for-year-in-sql)